# Cannot import name psyco_gevent

Tags: python, django, gevent-socketio

I have an import error with

```
from psycogreen.gevent import psyco_gevent
psyco_gevent.make_psycopg_green()
```

it says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name psyco_gevent
```

I installed `psycopg2` and `psycogreen`; and I followed this [nice article](http://www.pixeldonor.com/2014/jan/10/django-gevent-and-socketio/) about Django, Gevent, and Socket.io. [This article](http://blog.dbinit.com/going-green) also talks about it (it might be the source of the first article) and talks about a file named `psyco_gevent.py` on bitbucket which is not available anymore (404 error).

Answer (score 2):

For the psycogreen, it does look like its changed a bit. Check it out on bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/overview

It looks like this code:

```
from psycogreen.gevent import psyco_gevent
psyco_gevent.make_psycopg_green()
```

Should be changed to the same as the other psycogreen calls:

```
from psycogreen.gevent import patch_psycopg
patch_psycopg()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from a similar question like this when I import a model named as `greenlet`:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'greenlet'

I don't know exactly the reason but I resolved the problem by renaming the file name `greenlet.py` to `gl.py`. **Maybe we can't name a file by a model's name.**